# Issue with Docker linux containers on Windows 2019

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, sitespeedio

I am facing issue while pulling Sitespeed image in Docker running on Windows Server 2019, this however works fine while using Docker Desktop on Windows 10.

**PS C:\Sitespeed> docker info**
Client:
Context:    default
Debug Mode: false
Plugins:
app: Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
cluster: Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
registry: Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)

Server:
Containers: 0
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 20.10.7
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
Windows:
LCOW:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.1911)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 48GiB
Name: TITAN-201
ID: 4H6Y:QSND:DBPU:5BOG:WWO3:2QQS:HD54:BLYH:3SDD:FTXH:56OL:RN2F
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode: false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

**PS C:\Sitespeed> docker pull sitespeedio/sitespeed.io**
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from sitespeedio/sitespeed.io
7b1a6ab2e44d: Pull complete
bcb4974c0deb: Pull complete
77a421e32a02: Pull complete
8bd632b8efc3: Pull complete
942355027341: Pull complete
1e27cb521d29: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
cf72937d856a: Pull complete
681fa6bf53a9: Pull complete
c817bdd68a11: Pull complete
2fecef929f71: Pull complete
134027b45827: Pull complete
7389adaf2698: Pull complete
e8b6fefb903a: Pull complete
ae6f57572e5d: Pull complete
ea4212fcc5d6: Pull complete
9a149b9510ab: Download complete
81758f1fd3c7: Download complete
28531e33d129: Download complete
f13785a12256: Download complete
2bc054a28005: Download complete
b01ed0ff33fc: Download complete
21209f5f8994: Download complete
8f4a91166a41: Download complete
e27bb1f1deec: Download complete
**failed to register layer: re-exec error: failed to start service utility VM (diffgetter b4bbd55cc342d8d45b2870bbc0dd227d6b9f9f0e70379b7c08a458e794fbdb42): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem b4bbd55cc342d8d45b2870bbc0dd227d6b9f9f0e70379b7c08a458e794fbdb42_svm: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.: stderr:**

Any suggestion what is missed - have tried lots of options from other post, but luck so far.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Linux container on windows you will need WSL.
Here is the guide on how to install WSL on Windows Server 2019.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server